# Moving an object with multiple layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In CC 15 I could select an image with the lasso tool, then select the component parts of the image which exist on multiple layers and use the Move tool to adjust the image. It seems that CC 19 has eliminated this highly useful tool. Is there a workaround?

Comment: It still exists. Check the documentation: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/tools.html

Comment: The question tag says Photoshop, but it was never possible in Photoshop to move a selection of several layers. Also you've mentioned components, like vector component? But you can't select those with lasso. Please clarify the question.

Comment: Sergey, I design characters in Photoshop for an animation studio. The way I work is to put my line art on the top layer and color or tone on a different layer. When I move a line element, I would select the other layers and adjust them, too. Why is this suddenly so hard?